# Bootstrap fix conflict for a specific element and its children

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im having problem because of bootstrap applying css in some element like h2, h3, h4, etc...

Here is the code i see in bootstrap, note that it is applying styles to these elements

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
```

Here's my sample code :

```
<div class="page-wrapper">

<!-- OK to be added styles by boostrap -->
<div class="container">
    <h2><span>WELCOME BOOTSTRAP</span></h2>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap should not add styles to this div and its children.
This HTML is generated from external source and i just grab it and append it in DOM.
All styles here are inline.
If no inline styles applied, then stay it as is and dont let boostrap add other styles.     
-->

<div class="mycontent">
    <h2 style="font-style:italic;">
        <span style="color:#FFFFFF;"><span style="font-size: 72px;">NO BOOSTRAP HERE PLS!</span</span>
    </h2>
</div>

</div>
```

How can i achieve that the h2 inside class "mycontent" will ignore the bootstrap styles? I mean h2 should not have these styles : color: inherit; font-family: inherit;font-weight: 500;line-height: 1.1; which i meantioned above

**IMPORTANT NOTE** : I cannot edit/add styles to the div with class "myconent" since this is generated from other source. All i want to do is not let the bootstrap add styles of specific element and its children.

Any suggestion would really be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, simply add the following to your CSS:

```
div.myContent h2{
 /* YOUR STYLES */
}
```

There should be enough [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) there to override Bootstrap's baked in styles. Note- you will need to put this CSS below Bootstraps CSS file.

For any style you want to override- simply add more specificity to the rule in question, or replicate it and replace the properties you're interested in. As long as your CSS is placed after Bootstraps any rules will replace those already specified.

Comment: Hmm looks like it is not what i want. As ive mentioned above, class "myContent" is generated from external source and i just appended it in the DOM for display. I cannot add additional styles to it. If it has no styles applied then it should stay as is. No other styles like bootstrap should override it.

Comment: So you cant add any CSS to your page?

Comment: I can add any CSS in my page. However class "mycontent" and its children  shouldnt be overriden by those other CSS(bootstrap). In other words, all styles in bootstrap should exclude ONLY the "mycontent" class and its children. Hope my point is clear. Thank you for replying

Comment: If you add bootstrap's CSS first, any custom styling you have for any elements will override it as long as your rules have more specificity.   Unless you rewrite the bootstrap.css using a lot of `:not(.myContent)`  rules, your only solution is then to specifically put styles for `myContent` after bootstrap.css

Comment: I was thinking to add :not(.myContent) rule as you mentioned but i think it would take time. Im hoping for a faster and easier solution.
Thanks for replying and im glad you understood my problem. Thx